# Fastest way to generate random numbers

Tags: random, rust, libc

libc has [`random`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html) which

> uses a nonlinear additive feedback random number generator employing a default table of size 31 long integers to return successive pseudo-random numbers

I'm looking for a random function written in Rust with the same speed. It doesn't need to be crypto-safe, pseudo-random is good enough.

Looking through the [`rand crate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/index.html) it seems that [`XorShiftRng`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/struct.XorShiftRng.html) is the closest fit to this need:

> The Xorshift algorithm is not suitable for cryptographic purposes but is very fast

When I use it like this:

```
extern crate time;
use rand::Rng;

let mut rng = rand::XorShiftRng::new_unseeded();
rng.next_u64();
```

it is about 33% slower than libc's random. ([Sample code generating 8'000'000 random numbers](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=de0c94e53cdbb04e9dd673ae90a82d3d&version=nightly)).

In the end, I'll need `i64` random numbers, so when I run `rng.gen()` this is already 100% slower than libc's random. When casting with `rng.next_u64() as i64`, then is is 60% slower.

Is there any way to achieve the same speed in rust without using any `unsafe` code?

Comment: Just to make sure: you are compiling both in Release mode, right? (Because when I do use Release mode, in your example, XorShiftRng is completely optimized away... => http://play.integer32.com/?gist=29f3a3735ee52ab10790f96e4b248b6b&version=nightly)

Comment: uh, no, I didn't! In release mode the `XorShiftRng` version with `rng.gen()` is 760'000x as fast as `random()`. So my case is solved, but I don't understand why the release version is so much faster, and why XorShiftRng is now so much faster than `random()`

Comment: Because your benchmark is flawed (it's hard to benchmkar): everything is hard-coded, so the compiler optimizes the benchmark to `let start = time(); let end = time(); println!("...", start.to(end));`. This only happens for XorShiftRng because its implementation is available to the compiler, whereas the libc::random is dynamically loaded at run-time. My suggestion would be to use a realistic workload to evaluate them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Be sure to compile the code you are measuring in release mode, otherwise your benchmark is not representative of Rust's performance.

In order to obtain meaningful numbers, you must also modify the benchmark to do something with the generated numbers, e.g. collect them into a vector<sup>1</sup>. Failing to do so can make the compiler optimize the whole loop away because it has no side effects. This is what happened in your second attempt that led you to conclude that `XorShiftRng` is 760,000 thousand times faster than `libc::random`.

With the [changed benchmark](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=8a307a5bdf65d56e27fda6742c46f347&version=nightly) run in release mode, `XorShiftRng` ends up approximately 2x faster than `libc::random`:

```
PT0.101378490S seconds for libc::random
PT0.050827393S seconds for XorShiftRng
```

<sup>1</sup>
The compiler could also be smart enough to realize that the vector is also unused and optimize it away as well, but current `rustc` does not do so, and storing elements into a vector is enough. A simple and future-proof way to ensure that the generation is not optimized away is to sum up the numbers and write out the result.

Comment: what do you mean with "so the compiler can't optimize it away"?

Comment: If the compiler detects that you are not using a variable, it won't bother computing its value.

Comment: @hansaplast Rust's optimizing compiler will completely omit a loop that has no side effects. I've now updated the answer to explain that in more details.

Comment: one last question: why is the release build so much faster than the debug build? What is different in the generated executable compared to when building without `--release`?

Comment: @hansaplast Building for "release" tells `rustc` (and by extension to the underlying LLVM backend) to optimize for run-time efficiency. Optimizations can include smart register allocation, function inlining, loop unrolling, and many many others. The same goes for C, BTW, except that `libc` is *already* compiled with optimizations included, by your distribution. If you tried to compile libc's `random` without optimizations turned on, you would likely also see abysmal performance.